# confusion over using upgradable lock on std::map's find/insert

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, boost-mutex

Consider a thread-safe getter method in its,relatively, simplest form:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<AAA> > repo;
AAA & get(const std::string &key)
{
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(repoMutex);
    std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<AAA> >::iterator it = repo.find(key);
    if(it == repo.end()){       
        boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);
        boost::shared_ptr<AAA> t(new AAA(key));
        repo.insert(std::make_pair(key,t));
        return *t;
    }
    return *it->second;
}
```

in above, I use a shared(upgradeable) lock to protect a find operation, and upgrade to unique lock only if I need to insert a key/value. So far so good?

What I imagine is the following(please let me know if in any step my concept is wrong):

1. Two threads enter the method
2. Both are allowed to run `repo.find()` for the same key at the same time(and the key doesn't exist).
3. Both of them fail.as the key doesn't exist .
4. *first* thread gets exclusive access by entering the upgraded area, while the *second* thread waiting to enter upgraded area.
5. first thread finishes its job of creating a new entry for key and then
   walks off.
6. second thread enters and ***overwrites*** the key/value inserted by the first thread.(which is not what anybody wants)

How do we solve this issue? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, there's almost nothing wrong with your current solution.

First of all, the second thread won't overwrite the data written by the first one, because [map::insert()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) inserts only new keys. You only have to check if `insert` really inserted the element and return corresponding value.

The only concern is possible unwanted creation of `t` for nothing. In this case you can add another check after locking:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<AAA> >::iterator it = repo.find(key);
if(it == repo.end()){       
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);
    if (repo.find(key) == repo.end() {
        ...
    }
}
```

But you should profile your code to see if this gives you any advantage.

Also, you can utilize `map::insert()` with hint to avoid double searching for the key:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<AAA> >::iterator it = repo.find(key);
if(it == repo.end()){       
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);
    it = repo.lower_bound(key);
    if (it->first != key)
        boost::shared_ptr<AAA> t(new AAA(key));
        repo.insert(it, std::make_pair(key,t));
        return *t;        
    } else {
        return *it->second;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. BTW, as with the second option, `lower_bound` and `find` both have logarithmic time complexity. then they should take same amount of time. ?

Comment: @rahman I forgot to change the `insert` call, check the update. It takes an iterator as a hint and in this case has O(1) amortized complexity (see table 102 in the standard, look for `emplace_hint`).